# Getting all function arguments in haskel as list

Tags: haskell

Is there a way in haskell to get all function arguments as a list.

Let's supose we have the following program, where we want to add the two smaller numbers and then subtract the largest. Suppose, we can't change the function definition of `foo :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`. Is there a way to get all function arguments as a list, other than constructing a new list and add all arguments as an element of said list? More importantly, is there a general way of doing this independent of the number of arguments?

Example:

```
module Foo where
    import Data.List

    foo :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
    foo a b c = result!!0 + result!!1 - result!!2 where result = sort ([a, b, c])
```

Comment: Well in Haskell, every function has exactly *one* argument. `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int` is short for `Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Int))`.

Comment: I see. So there's no was to do it then. Would you like to make an answer out of your comment, then I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there a general way of doing this independent of the number of arguments?

Not really; at least it's not worth it. First off, this entire idea isn't very useful because lists are *homogeneous*: all elements must have the same type, so it only works for the rather unusual special case of functions which only take arguments of a single type.

Even then, the problem is that “number of arguments” isn't really a sensible concept in Haskell, because as Willem Van Onsem commented, all functions really only have *one* argument (further arguments are actually only given to the *result* of the first application, which has again function type).

That said, at least for a single argument- and final-result type, it is quite easy to pack any number of arguments into a list:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances         #-}

class UsingList f where
  usingList :: ([Int] -> Int) -> f

instance UsingList Int where
  usingList f = f []

instance UsingList r => UsingList (Int -> r) where
  usingList f a = usingList (f . (a:))

foo :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
foo = usingList $ (\[α,β,γ] -> α + β - γ) . sort
```

It's also possible to make this work for any type of the arguments, using type families or a multi-param type class. What's not so simple though is to write it once and for all with variable type of the final result. The reason being, that would also have to handle a *function* as the type of final result. But then, that could also be intepreted as “we still need to add one more argument to the list”!

Answer (score 4):

With all respect, I would disagree with [@leftaroundabout's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48950262/2108477). Something being
unusual is not a reason to shun it as unworthy.

It is correct that you would not be able to define a *polymorphic variadic list constructor*
without type annotations. However, we're not usually dealing with Haskell 98, where type
annotations were never required. With [Dependent Haskell](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DependentHaskell) just around the corner, some
familiarity with non-trivial type annotations is becoming vital.

So, let's take a shot at this, disregarding worthiness considerations.

---

One way to define a function that does not seem to admit a single type is to make it a method of a
suitably constructed class. Many a trick involving type classes were devised by cunning
Haskellers, starting at least as early as [15 years ago](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2003-April/011621.html). Even if we don't understand their
type wizardry in all its depth, we may still try our hand with a similar approach.

Let us first try to obtain a method for summing any number of Integers. That means repeatedly
applying a function like `(+)`, with a uniform type such as `a -> a -> a`. Here's one way to do
it:

```
class Eval a where
    eval :: Integer -> a

instance (Eval a) => Eval (Integer -> a) where
    eval i = \y -> eval (i + y)

instance Eval Integer where
    eval i = i
```

And this is the extract from repl:

```
λ eval 1 2 3 :: Integer
6
```

Notice that we can't do without explicit type annotation, because the very idea of our approach is
that an expression `eval x1 ... xn` may either be a function that waits for yet another argument,
or a final value.

One generalization now is to actually make a list of values. The science [tells us](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58553/278244) that
we may derive any monoid from a list. Indeed, insofar as sum is a monoid, we may turn arguments to
a list, then sum it and obtain the same result as above.

Here's how we can go about turning arguments of our method to a list:

```
class Eval a where
    eval2 :: [Integer] -> Integer -> a

instance (Eval a) => Eval (Integer -> a) where
    eval2 is i = \j -> eval2 (i:is) j

instance Eval [Integer] where
    eval2 is i = i:is
```

This is how it would work:

```
λ eval2 [] 1 2 3 4 5 :: [Integer]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Unfortunately, we have to make `eval` binary, rather than unary, because it now has to compose two
different things: a (possibly empty) list of values and the next value to put in. Notice how it's
similar to the usual `foldr`:

```
λ foldr (:) [] [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

The next generalization we'd like to have is allowing arbitrary types inside the list. It's a bit
tricky, as we have to make `Eval` a 2-parameter type class:

```
class Eval a i where
    eval2 :: [i] -> i -> a

instance (Eval a i) => Eval (i -> a) i where
    eval2 is i = \j -> eval2 (i:is) j

instance Eval [i] i where
    eval2 is i = i:is
```

It works as the previous with `Integer`s, but it can also *carry* any other type, even a function:

*(I'm sorry for the messy example. I had to `show` a function somehow.)*

```
λ ($ 10) <$> (eval2 [] (+1) (subtract 2) (*3) (^4) :: [Integer -> Integer])
[10000,30,8,11]
```

So far so good: we can convert any number of arguments into a list. However, it will be hard to
compose this function with the one that would do useful work with the resulting list, because
composition only admits unary functions − with some trickery, binary ones, but in no way the
variadic. Seems like we'll have to define our own way to compose functions. That's how I see it:

```
class Ap a i r where
    apply :: ([i] -> r) -> [i] -> i -> a
    apply', ($...) :: ([i] -> r) -> i -> a
    ($...) = apply'

instance Ap a i r => Ap (i -> a) i r where
    apply f xs x = \y -> apply f (x:xs) y
    apply' f x = \y -> apply f [x] y

instance Ap r i r where
    apply f xs x = f $ x:xs
    apply' f x = f [x]
```

Now we can write our desired function as an application of a list-admitting function to any number
of arguments:

```
foo' :: (Num r, Ord r, Ap a r r) => r -> a
foo' = (g $...)
    where f = (\result -> (result !! 0) + (result !! 1) - (result !! 2))
          g = f . sort
```

You'll still have to type annotate it at every call site, like this:

```
λ foo' 4 5 10 :: Integer
-1
```

− But so far, that's the best I can do.

---

The more I study Haskell, the more I am certain that nothing is impossible.